# Why rotation factor of bearing for inner ring is 1 and for outer ring is 1.2?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, bearings

V is a rotation factor to account for the difference in ball rotations for outer ring rotation vs. inner ring rotation.

V = 1 for inner ring rotation
V = 1.2 for outer ring rotation

From Shigley's Mechanical Engineering Design - Ninth Edition

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Source: Wikipedia's [Ball-bearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_bearing).*

The distance rolled on the inner ring is the same as the distance rolled on the outer ring. Due to the difference in circumference the ball will pass the same point on the inner ring about twice as often as it passes the same point on the outer ring (for these dimensions).